# How can a class inherit from a template based on itself?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

While reading an article, I came across the following syntax:

```
template <typename T>
class MyTemplate
{
    T* member;
    T* method();
    // ...
}

class MyClass : public MyTemplate<MyClass>
{
    // ...
}
```

I don't exactly understand how `MyClass` can inherit from a template that's based on itself. Could you please explain how this works?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is called the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), or CRTP for short. It is used to achieve the effect of static polymorphism by taking advantage of the fact that by the time you get to `MyTemplate<MyClass>` in the line `class MyClass : public MyTemplate<MyClass>`, `MyClass` is semi-defined (it is an incomplete type) so you can store pointers to that type, etc, and do things with it that do not require a complete type.

Comment: I would not say that `MyClass` is incomplete. It might be the case that you want some generic functionality be provided for this class. For instance [Example](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184403484).

Comment: @R.K at the point of `public MyTemplate<MyClass>`, `MyClass` is indeed an incomplete type. It means you can store pointers and references, etc.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now that i read your description again, it is correct. I thought you meant that MyClass is, for the example, an incomplete type.

Answer (score 3):

> Could you please explain how this works?

Uhm... it just.. does? The standard specifically allows template parameters to be of incomplete type. And since no method in the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) base class needs a fully defined type, everything is fine.

> §3.9.2 p3 [basic.compound]
> Pointers to incomplete types are allowed although there are restrictions on what can be done with them (3.11).
>
> §14.3.1 p2 [temp.arg.type]
> [ Note: A template type argument may be an incomplete type (3.9). —end note ]

Answer (score 2):

This is called CRTP. It is used for static polymorphism which can be faster than using virtual.

```
: public MyTemplate<MyClass>
```

Instantiates `MyTemplate<MyClass>`, although since MyClass is incomplete you can only use `T` in ways that don't require a complete type. Such as using a pointer or calling a member function.

Anyway, just look at your snippet, it's essentially the same as this:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass* member;
    MyClass* method();
}
```

Which is perfectly legal and understandable.