# C++ template class inherit itself

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, eigen

I have some trouble in reading some source codes from Eigen library. 
Here is the base class **TensorBase**:

```
template<typename Derived>
class TensorBase<Derived, ReadOnlyAccessors> {
  ...
};
```

In the following code, How can the base class **TensorBase** inherit itself? What's the point of using this inheritance? Is this common?

```
template<typename Derived, int AccessLevel = 
         internal::accessors_level<Derived>::value>
class TensorBase : public TensorBase<Derived, ReadOnlyAccessors> {
  ...
};
```

Comment: Is there any chance it is similar with this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46236565/how-can-a-class-inherit-itself/46236632
or
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336220/how-can-a-class-inherit-from-a-template-based-on-itself

Comment: A class cannot inherit itself indeed, but TensorBase is not a class. It's a class template. A specialisation of a class template can inherit another specialisation of the same template.

Comment: @n.m. I got it. A specialization is just a different class.

Comment: @aliyasineser: The first link just answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: @YulongAo very welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class is not inheriting from itself. It is inheriting from a different instantiation of the same template. Remember, different instantiations of the same template are different types.

For illustration, consider this simple albeit contrived example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <int N>
struct foo : foo<N-1> {};

template <> 
struct foo<0> {
    static const int value = 23;
};


int main() {
    std::cout << foo<23>::value;
    return 0;
}
```

`foo<23>` inherits from `foo<22>` which in turn inherits from `foo<21>` and so on until eventually `foo<0>` does not inherit from anything.

In your case it seems like read-only functionality is implemented in a base class that is inherited from the instantiations for different access levels.